# Hide and show toggle/ change button colour, not working with function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a strange issue, i have a toggle that hide and shows information and changes colour onclick . it works perfectly on the page i built the code on. For example the button background changes colour when the toggle is open and changes back when the toggle is closed, as i am echoing out data from the DB, i have had to call my script inside a function for it to work, but now the script doesn't change colour or work as required. I believe it is the function causing the issue, is there a alternative to function.

I am very new, and don't seem to know why this is not working, any help will appreciated.

```js
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var button = document.querySelector('.button');
            button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                var target = document.querySelector(button.getAttribute('data-target'));
                if (target.style.display == "none") {
                    target.style.display = "block";
                    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute('data-shown-text');
                    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                     button.style.border = "thick dashed #0000FF";
                } else {
                    target.style.display = "none";
                    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute('data-hidden-text');
                    button.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                   
                }
            
            });
               }
```

```html
    echo("<div id='first_product'>");
        echo("<div class='button' data-target='#text' data-shown-text='Hide'   onclick='toggle_visibility(\"text\")  data-hidden-text='Mich'>" . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </div>");


        
            echo("<div id='text' class ='hidden'>");
```

Comment: I can see formatting issue - no ending quote at `onclick='toggle_visibility(\"text\") `. Is it due to copy/paste?

Comment: Or do you see any error messages in devtools console (in browser)?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev i think it may be, ill check my original and see if I've accidentally left anything out. No errors at all

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing single-quote here:

```
onclick='toggle_visibility(\"text\")
```

Worked for me after adding that in:

```
onclick='toggle_visibility(\"text\")'
```

Comment: The code works in HTML. But not when i am trying to eco data out of a query, and thats my problem. It toggles but does not change colour. In in HTML in works fine